# Mono.Simd Vector3 (floats) missing?

Tags: c#, mono, vector, simd

Heya, I'm trying to use Mono's SIMD to handle coordinates(X,Y,Z) in my project,
but I only see support for Vector2 and Vector4 types. Has anyone run into this before, and are there any workarounds?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's connected to the way the registers work. You can just use the Vector4f and set the `W` part to 0, or 1 (depending on what you want to do with the vector) and everything will be ok.

http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Nov-03.html explains:

> On x86 processors these instructions
>   use a new register bank (the XMM
>   registers) and can be configured to
>   work on 16 bytes at a time using a
>   number of possible combinations:
>
> ```
> * byte-level operations on 16 elements.
> * short-level operations on 8 elements.
> * single precision or integer-level operations on 4 elements.
> * double precision or long-integer operations on 2 elements.
> ```